# XSRF in a RESTful Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, csrf

I am a ASP.NET Developer trying to learn Rails and RESTful approach. To understand, I am planning to write a Email client, which would make RESTful GET call to the server to fetch the emails and POST to send an email.

What are the best practices (both generic and/or specific to Rails) to be followed so that, the above application is not exposing any XSRF vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Ruby on Rails Security Project](http://www.rorsecurity.info/2008/05/05/csrf-an-underestimated-attack-method/) has a good post on this.

Essentially, Rails 2.0 and above have built-in protection for XSRF attacks.  Every form created via the form helpers includes a hidden field with a special token in it.  Each time a POST (or non-GET) is received, the token is checked against a secret on the server.  If they don't match, a security exception is thrown and the request is ignored.

Read the article.  They do a better job explaining it.