# In Rails, do you need to use form_authenticity_token if you're already checking if a user is logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication, forms-authentication

Because form_authenticity_token is used to validate requests, is it redundant to use it when you're already checking whether a user is logged in?

I.e., is form_authenticity_token really intended only for forms which are available to anyone, as opposed to forms exclusively for logged-in users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being logged in would make an XSRF attack worse, because then it could actually damage real data.  Check these out as a starting point.

[XSRF in a RESTful Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253327/xsrf-in-a-restful-application)

[Cross-Site Request Forgeries and You](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001171.html)

Answer (score 0):

No because in CSRF attacks requests are sent by the client's browser which is authenticated and may delete his data.

Read the [Ruby on Rails Security Guide section about CSRF](http://guides.rails.info/security.html#cross-site-reference-forgery-csrf).